# How to cleanly remove a non-storage USB device

Tags: linux, usb

Is there a way in Linux to cleanly remove (i.e. 'safely remove') a USB device that is not a mass storage device before it is unplugged?

**My problem:**

I have a USB TV stick - a 'Mygica T230 DVB-T/T2/C'.

It works ok, and usually when I unplug it, syslog reports that it is 'successfully disconnected' and then the USB port can subsequently be used again as normal.

However, sometimes this isn't the case: I unplug it and the system doesn't realize that it has been disconnected. `lsusb` reports that it is still connected and the USB port is unusable until I reboot the computer. When I do reboot the computer it hangs, forcing me to hold the power button.

What I need is to be able to tell the computer to disconnect the device before I unplug it.

For an external hard drive I would use:

```
$ udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdx
```

Is there an equivalent command for non mass storage devices?